# How do I access an JSON array with boost::property_tree?

Tags: json, boost

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    // string s = "{\"age\":23,\"study\":{\"language\":{\"one\":\"chinese\",\"subject\":[{\"one\":\"china\"},{\"two\":\"Eglish\"}]}}}";

    string s = "{\"age\" : 26,\"person\":[{\"id\":1,\"study\":[{\"language\":\"chinese\"},{\"language1\":\"chinese1\"}],\"name\":\"chen\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"zhang\"}],\"name\" : \"huchao\"}";
    ptree pt;
    stringstream stream(s);
    read_json<ptree>( stream, pt);

    int s1=pt.get<int>("age");
    cout<<s1<<endl;

    string s2 = pt.get<string>("person."".study."".language1");
    cout<<s2<<endl;
```

Now I want to get the value of language1.

Comment: You _did_ get the value of "language1". It's the string you got from your last `pt.get` statement; you stored ti in `s2`. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: I want to know how to get the value of "language1" through pt.get statement.But I don't know how to get it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I've got to ask why you have a list with such different elements in it? If `language1` has some special meaning, then I would split the data up into `study` and `study1` or something like that. In general, lists should be of a single type.

Assuming you can't change the format, here is the answer to your question. To the best of my knowledge, the only way to get something out of an array is to iterate over it.

```
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

BOOST_FOREACH(const ptree::value_type& val, pt.get_child("person.study"))
{
  boost::optional<string> language1Option = v.second.get_optional<string>("language1");
  if(language1Option) {
    cout<<"found language1: "<<*language1Option<<endl;
  }
}
```

This code iterates over everything in the "study" list and looks for an entry with a "language1" key, printing the result